# Converts Postfix to Expression Tree and Evaluate Expression Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

```
public static ExpressionTreeNode Postfix2ExpressionTree(String postfixExpr) {
    return root;
} // end-Postfix2ExpressionTree
```

The above method should work like this, take a postfix, converts this postfix to an expression tree and returns a pointer to the root of the tree.

```
public static int EvaluateExpressionTree(ExpressionTreeNode root) {
    // Fill this in
    return -1;
} // end-EvaluateExpressionTree
```

The above method should work like this,Take a pointer to the root of an expression tree, evaluates the expression tree, and returns the result.

Also there is a class:

```
public class ExpressionTreeNode {
    public byte type; // 0: operator, 1: operand (a number)
    public char operator; // One of '+', '-', '*', '/'
    public int operand; // A number

    public ExpressionTreeNode left, right; // Left & right children

    ExpressionTreeNode(byte type) {
        this.type = type;
        left = right = null;
    }
```

Finally, my question is that how can I create a constructor in `ExpressionTreeNode` class to converts postfix to expression tree easily and which algorithm should I use to methods work.

Thank everyone who reads..

Comment: Why? You don't need a tree for postfix. Just a stack.

Comment: I made it using the stack but I couldn't do it this way. I need because teacher wanted @EJP